# Manage tab content with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a tab navigation using bootstrap+jquery like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tag1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
</ul>

<div ng-app="app">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1"></div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I would like to manage just the content of each pane with angular. Like this

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1" ng-controller="Tab1Ctrl"></div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2" ng-controller="Tab2Ctrl"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible with angular? Each controller would have to load its own template and fill it with data. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about using ng-view?

Comment: Isn't that pretty much what Angular does by default?

Comment: @Codezilla there is no routing in the above code, so how would I apply a template to a controller. usually this is done by providing templateUrl in routing provider

Comment: Using ng-include might help then.

Comment: You should be able to do this using ng-include. Each template would have its own controller. Also if you wish to load only the default template initially and stop all the other templates from loading, ng-include is the way to go.

Comment: @Codezilla hwo would ng-include stop loading?

Comment: You can update the src attribute of ng-include on demand. Keep a scope model inside src : src="pathTemplate2" which initially would be an empty string. Now when you click on Tab2 the ng-click handler would update it to the actual path of the template: $scope.pathTemplate2 = 'partials/tab2.html'.

Comment: @Codezilla can you post this as an answer with example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-include:

```
<ng-include src="pathTemplate1" ng-controller="Tab1Ctrl"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="pathTemplate2" ng-controller="Tab2Ctrl"></ng-include>
```

When the user selects a tab, update the source using ng-click handler:

```
$scope.pathTemplate2 = "partials/tab2.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using angular-ui-router. Not only you avail of the classi ng-view behaviour but you can change controller on a tab depending on the application state.
Look at this [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).